# Redis Subscription + Rails ActionController::Live hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, publish-subscribe

In a single controller of a simple Rails 5 app, I have 2 actions (`live` and `test`), both using `ActionController::Live`. `live` goes through a loop and write random data to `response.stream.write` without any issues. It works.

In `test` however, I am using Redis.subscribe. Here is the action code:

```rb
        def test
            response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

            redis = Redis.new

                redis.subscribe_with_timeout(30, "abc") do |on|
                    on.message do |event, data|
                        puts data
                        response.stream.write data
                    end
                end
        rescue IOError
            # ignore
        ensure
            redis.quit
            response.stream.close
        end
```

The `test` method however doesn't work as expected. This is what happens:

I start the app and hit the `test` endpoint with `curl`. Curl stops waiting for data as expected.
Then in `redis-cli` I send a message to the `abc` channel. Immediately I see my message in the rails app window (`puts data`) and I see this in curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 25df052d-e3f2-4327-9a97-088e702460fa
X-Runtime: 2.709001
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But while the all the consequent messages from `redis-cli` are printed on the rails side, they are not received by curl until the timeout is over (30 seconds in `subscribe_with_timeout`).

I am running Puma, have looked and implemented at all Stackoverflow answers regarding concurreny, heartbeat threads and more with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, it turned out you'd need a new line `"\n"` at the end of anything that goes out to `response.stream.write` for it to get out of the buffer.